# Using "or" in a variable, but its not allowing the 2nd option to be used as a correct input

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

I am writing a basic program in python to guess a favorite food. I made a variable `answer` with two options of `"pizza" or "Pizza"` because they're going to be input from a user and I don't want capitalized words to give a false negative when guessing.
However when i test the program and type the 2nd option `"Pizza"` it does result in an incorrect guess. The very thing i was trying to prevent. I cant figure out why.

```
answer = "pizza" or "Pizza"
guess = input("What's my favorite food? ")
counter = 1

while (guess != answer):
    counter += 1
    if guess == answer:
        print("Yep! So amazing!")
    else:
        print("Yuck! That’s not it!")
        guess = input("Try again. ")


print("Correct!")
print("Thanks for playing! It took you " + str(counter) + " guesses.")
```

**side question:** I think my `while` loop is written incorrectly for a correct guess... while it works as intended if i type `"pizza"` this piece of code here :

```
if guess == answer:
        print("Yep! So amazing!")
```

doesnt seem to do anything. but its also not messing anything up.

Comment: [`or`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: Python does not support quantum-state variables.  You need to learn to detect any of a list of values; see the duplicate for details.  Your code sets `answer = True`; the rest of your difficulties follow directly from that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`answer = "pizza" or "Pizza"` evaluates the expression to `"pizza"` before assigning that value to `answer`. You want a set that stores *both* `"pizza"` and `"Pizza"`, then check if `guess` is in that set later.

```
answer = set(["pizza","Pizza"])
guess = input("What's my favorite food? ")
counter = 1

while True:
    counter += 1
    if guess in answer:
        print("Yep! So amazing!")
        break

    print("Yuck! That’s not it!")
    guess = input("Try again. ")
```

If `answer` is just a collection of the same string using different upper and lowercase letters, though, just store `"pizza"` and convert the guess to lowercase before a directly comparison.

```
answer = "pizza"
...
while True:
    ...
    if guess.lower() == answer:
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Other pages i checked for  this answer never showed me `set`.

Also `break` is new to me too... previously my code was NOT printing  `"Yep. So amazing!"`
is that what did it?

Comment: Before, if you guess `pizza` on the first try, `guess != answer` was false, so the loop was never entered.